# Resuming and suspendig WinRT Camera App

Tags: c#, windows-phone, runtime, resume, suspend

I have an app with three pages: `MainPage`, `Page2` and `Page3`. At `MainPage` I have my camera, at `Page2` I have the historical with the scans from MainPage, and my `Page3` has some infos about the app. My issue is when I Suspend and when I Resume it. It suspends ok, but when I press the resume button at Visual Studio LifeStyle Events I get the following error `A remote operation is taken longer then expected`. As you can see, my app is taking to much time to be resumed.

At my `App.xaml.cs` I have this OnSuspending method:

```
public App()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.Suspending += this.OnSuspending;
}

private void OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
{
    var deferral = e.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();
     deferral.Complete();
}
```

And in my `MainPage` I have this Resuming Method:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    Application.Current.Resuming += App_resuming;
}

async void App_resuming(object sender, object 
{
    if (Frame.Content == this)
    await InitializeCamera();
}
```

I think I have to dispose my camera when I suspend the app, so I created an Suspend Method at `MainPage` also, where I dispose my camera

```
void App_suspending(object sender, Windows.ApplicationModel.SuspendingEventArgs e)
{
   _mediaCapture.Dispose();
}
```

So, just reformulating my question: What am I doing is right? What am I missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could reproduce your problem when i am not disposing camera object on suspend, which you said you have tried but still its taking longer time. What i can suggest you to check camera object if it really getting dispose. To make sure you can add below lines of code in OnSuspend:

```
await cameraCapture.StopPreview();
cameraCapture.Dispose();
cameraCapture = null;
```

and in resume before initializing camera, create object again.